# Cannot make the views counter

Tags: python, django, view, counter, blogs

I'm Trying to create a Views Counter in my django blog. Their are 3 apps in the project. The views counter on the writings app works fine but on the blog app it throws an error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'views'` and shows the error at `post.views+=1`. However the same code works in the writings app. I cannot find where the problem lies. Maybe the code is returning a empty set that's why it's not working but if so then why the code works when I remove just this views counter code?

Here are the code snippets for Blog and Writings app.
**Blog app Views.py:-**

```
    post = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
    post.views +=1
    post.save()
    tech = Tech.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
    tech.views +=1
    tech.save()
    pcomments = BlogComment.objects.filter(post=post,parent=None)
    preplies = BlogComment.objects.filter(post=post).exclude(parent=None)
    #Creating Reply Dictionary and iterating it 
    preplyDict = {}
    for reply in preplies:
        if reply.parent.sno not in preplyDict.keys():
            preplyDict[reply.parent.sno] = [reply]
        else:
            preplyDict[reply.parent.sno].append(reply)
    tcomments = BlogComment.objects.filter(tech=tech,parent=None)
    treplies = BlogComment.objects.filter(tech=tech).exclude(parent=None)
    #Creating Reply Dictionary and iterating it 
    treplyDict = {}
    for reply in treplies:
        if reply.parent.sno not in treplyDict.keys():
            treplyDict[reply.parent.sno] = [reply]
        else:
            treplyDict[reply.parent.sno].append(reply)
    context = {'post': post,'tech': tech,'pcomments':pcomments,'tcomments':tcomments,'preplyDict':preplyDict,'treplyDict':treplyDict}
    return render(request,'blog/blogPost.html',context)
```

**Writings views.py:-**

```
def wPost(request,slug):
    w = Writing.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
    w.views = w.views+1
    w.save()
    comments = WComment.objects.filter(wpost=w, parent=None)
    replies = WComment.objects.filter(wpost=w).exclude(parent=None)
    #Creating Reply Dictionary and iterating it 
    replyDict = {}
    for reply in replies:
        if reply.parent.sno not in replyDict.keys():
            replyDict[reply.parent.sno] = [reply]
        else:
            replyDict[reply.parent.sno].append(reply)
    context = {'writings': w,'comments': comments,'user' : request.user,'replyDict' : replyDict}
    return render(request,'writings/wPost.html', context)
```

**Blog Models.py:-**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    sno= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=150,default=" ")
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="blog/", blank=True)
    img2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="blog/", blank=True)
    img3 = models.ImageField(upload_to="blog/", blank=True)
    img4 = models.ImageField(upload_to="blog/", blank=True)
    img5 = models.ImageField(upload_to="blog/", blank=True)
    img6 = models.ImageField(upload_to="blog/", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' by ' + self.author
class Tech(models.Model):
    sno= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=150,default=" ")
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="blog/", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' by ' + self.author
```

**Writing Models.py**

```
class Writing(models.Model):
    sno= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=150,default=" ")
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="writings/", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' by ' + self.author
```

**Blog admin.py:-**

```
admin.site.register(BlogComment)

#Add this media to the post while registering it.
@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ("tinyinject.js",)

@admin.register(Tech)
class TechAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ("tinyinject.js",)
```

**Writings admin.py:-**

```
admin.site.register(WComment)

@admin.register(Writing)
class WriteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ("tinyinject.js",)
```

**Error Starctrace:-**

```
None
Internal Server Error: /blog/learning-python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/skyrunner/django_blog/mendlife/blogenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/skyrunner/django_blog/mendlife/blogenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/skyrunner/django_blog/mendlife/blogenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/skyrunner/django_blog/mendlife/blog/views.py", line 18, in blogPost
    post.views+=1
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'views'
```

Comment: Can you add the full error stacktrace, so we can see what line raises the error and see the call stack?

Comment: NoneType object suggests that the post variable is empty. Therefore `Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()` returns None apparently.

Comment: @vincent Yes you are right. I tried printing the post object and it returns none. However it's weird because if it returns none then it should throw an error outright isnt't it? but the later code is still working and the posts are still showing. More weird because the same code works in writings app. And the same query returns the desired result but it doesn't in the case of the Blog app.

Comment: @Ralf I pushed the code with the bug to another 'Bug' Named branch. Here is the Link to it - https://github.com/skyrunner360/django_blog/tree/bug

Comment: Because you use filter() and first() it will not return an error, but None. Are you sure that there is a Post in your database with the slug you have from the url?

Comment: @Vincent Yes their is a post. I checked the DB many times. It's there. If their wasn't then shouldn't I get an empty string or something instead of my post's data?

Comment: @RishiMathur on what url do you try to render blogPost view on?

Comment: @Vincent /blog/<str:slug>. Although I don't think it has something to do with the url as URLs are working just fine.

Comment: Try changing the urls in your template to `href="{% url "blogPost" slug=post.slug %}"` and add a `/` at the end of the urls defined in urls.py

Comment: @Vincent Tried. Doesn't work. same error.

Comment: Here's an update. It worked for a brief moment after I did this- I deleted the sqlite file and migrated again, added a test blog and then for that first blog it worked, however as I added another testblog the same error comes again. I think their's something going on with the database and sql part here. Don't know how this observation helps but if it helps then please help me. I couldn't find any possible solution to this problem anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

So after wasting hours I realised i made a very silly mistake there. As I'm using two models I just simply had to use an If statement. so I added this and it worked as desired

```
if post is None:
        tech.views +=1
        tech.save()
    else:
        post.views+=1
        post.save()
```

Thank you for everybody's comments and feedbacks!